# How can i host a local website to domain using nginx?

Tags: port, port-forwarding, localhost, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a server that is running at `127.0.0.1:8323`

This port is not reachable from outside.

I want to provide this ip address as `https://example.com/website/index.php` over the port 80

How can i do this using nginx?

I have tried using `proxy_pass` in a server, like :

```
server {
listen 80;
location website/ {
proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8323;
 }
}
```

But it returns 404

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to provide the site with TLS it should be on port 443, not 80 (see [RFC 9110, 4.2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#section-4.2.2)).
- The service on localhost:8323 might not have TLS; in this case you should not try to access it with `https://`.
- The [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) defined as a *prefix string* should start with a `/`.

Minimum TLS configuration would be:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         example.com;
    ssl_certificate     /path/to/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/example.com.key;

    location /website/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8323;
    }
}
```